# Inserting the fields value to SQL Database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, custom-field-types

I have Form that i created in infopath and published it to SharePoint 2013
Could it be possible to insert the field value to SQL Database?
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current settings / requirements you can select the appropriate solution from the following.

1. Create an Event Receiver on your list at `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated` to write to SQL Database but this requires coding.

   - You can check a full example for Item added at [Create a Custom List Level Event Receiver For Item Added To SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/)
2. You can work with BCS External List to read and write your data from external data source like SQL database , in this case, you can customize your forms via InfoPath as mentioned at an article on MSDN [Customize External List Forms Using Microsoft InfoPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554886.aspx) but this will need to configuration BCS and recreate your current list as External List.
3. There's another alternative solution from InfoPath (I didn't try it before) where You can use a secondary data connection to a Web service that works with that database. for more details check [Add a data connection to a Microsoft SQL Server database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-data-connection-to-a-Microsoft-SQL-Server-database-c26193cc-8520-4941-adec-1df637bbf03a)